# concentric square number using python

Tags: python

i try to make square number but i stuck to print * in middle of square, the program should not using list cause this simple basic. i use looping with if else. i have try my best, maybe someone want's help me to fixed it.

sample

```
input:
5
a
8
output:
88888
8aaa8
8a*a8
8aaa8
8aaa8
```

my code:

```
a = int(input("Enter number: "))
b = input("Enter string: ")
c = int(input("Enter number: "))
row = 1

while(row <= a):
    column = 1
    while(column <= a ):
        if(row == 1 or row == a or column == 1 or column == a):          
            print(c, end = ' ')
        elif(row == a / 2 or column == a / 2)://this for * in middle
            print("*" - 2, end=" ")
        else:
            print(b, end = ' ')
        column = column + 1
    row = row + 1
    print()
```

My code that I have commented in line does not print right results, which should print *.

Answer (score 1):

`elif(row == a / 2 or column == a / 2)` change your code to `elif(row == a // 2+1 and column == a // 2+1)` and remove `-2` from `print('*' - 2)`

---

```
while(row <= a):
    column = 1
    while(column <= a ):
        if(row == 1 or row == a or column == 1 or column == a):          
            print(c, end = ' ')
        elif(row == a // 2+1 and column == a // 2+1):
            print("*", end=" ")
        else:
            print(b, end = ' ')
        column = column + 1
    row += 1
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Integer Division` feature of Python. 
You wrote `a/2` which gives floating value `2.5`.
But, `a//2` gives integer `2`

Try this for `line: 11, 12`:

```
    elif((row == 1 + (a // 2)) and (column == 1 + (a // 2))):  # this for * in middle
        print("*", end=" ")
```

Comment: If you have any other logic please share. In my solution I have all ready done that.